# Insert checkbox selected value to textbox in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I have 5 asp.net checkboxes in webform ...i want as the checkboxes checked and unchecked then its text will be added in textbox i.e if checkbox 1 and checkbox9 will be checked then in textbox the text will be 1,9 and if checkbox1 is unchecked then the textbox text will be 9

How to do this using javascript, vb.net or Jquery

I dont have any idea how to do it ...

CODE I FOUND :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Test(control, value) {
     var str = '';
     $('#<%=txtTest.ClientID %> :checked').each(function() {
       str = str + ', ' $(this).val();
     });
     $('#<%=txtTest.ClientID %>').val(str);

</script>
```

ITS NOT WORKING ...

Comment: I have problems and problem ...beacuse i dont know how to do this, i want sample code for this ?

Comment: ok your 1 step closer to getting help. Now what exactly is _NOT working_?

Comment: The code you posted needs to be CALLED from somewhere - we need to see at least the asp for the textfield and checkbox and somewhere you need to have a call of Test(...) However when I read a question about how to collect some stuff in a form to put somewhere else in a form, I always suspect it is because the asker has a problem reading the values on the server. WHY would you want to add the checked stuff to another field instead of just reading the checked values on the server?

Comment: Can anybody redit this code to get it working ..m using asp.net standard checkboxes and textbox

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, you need to give the checkboxes a class of checkBoxClass. The following has NOT been tested!

```
$(function() {     
   $(".checkBoxClass").each("click", function() { // whenever a checkbox is clicked
     var str = "";
     /* get all checked checkboxes of this name - class can be used too, 
        but using name, you can have sets of checkboxes */
     $("input[name=$(this).attr('name')] :checked").each(function() { 
       str += ", " + $(this).val(); // append the value
     });
     // add it to the textfield, if there is something to add
     $("#<%=txtTest.ClientID %>").val(str?str.substring(2):"");
   });
});
```

Comment: where to replace coding if i have checkbox1 , checkbox2 and this type of checkboxes and textbox ?

Comment: Error in this line ...str = str + ', ' $(this).val(); // append the value 

expected ';' near $

Comment: Missed a plus. added now. Not sure about `name=$(this).name` or `name=$(this).attr('name')`

Comment: That is likely because I do not have enough information. For example if the id of the field is correct. Show the view-source of the page

Comment: @Sanja: Do you have jquery reference? Also not working means error or simply not working?